# React On Rails - Rails structure for hydrating data using React Router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-on-rails

I'm setting up a project using [react-on-rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) to do initial rendering server side.  I've got it integrated with react-router and successfully working to render server side for the initial load of any given page, and react-router takes over from there and acts as a regular React client side app/router.  I am not sure of the best way to go about initially loading `props` though, as the initial page could be any "page" of the site.  I'm not finding any integration examples of this online.

For example, if a request is made to `/page-one`, it needs different data sent in as props for the server rendering than a request made to `/page-two`.

In Rails, all requests are redirected to the index view, which contains `react_component` which in turn renders the correct page.

routes.rb:

```
get "*path", to: "index#index"
```

index/index.html.erb:

```
<%= react_component("DemoApp", props: {test: "hello"}, prerender: true) %>
```

This is working great, but how to populate those props based on the page being requested?

It would be great if when doing the server side rendering, the (what would normally be) async calls to fetch data would happen server side, then props don't matter.  Is this possible?  Or am I going to have to dynamically determine what props should be and have a separate server side process to handle that, in addition to the existing APIs that would normally be fetched via client side AJAX requests?

I feel like I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle here, just not sure what exactly it is.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Comment: Yes, I ended up setting up routes within rails to match those incoming requests.  Then you can organize your controllers and actions as you would in a typical project.  The actions can perform the necessary logic and set a variable containing the necessary props for that action.  Those actions then call a method within the application controller which is essentially just a helper method that renders the view that initializes React.